# Why is my javascript form not submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firebase

I am creating a form that directly inject the data contained in the text fields to firebase via POST method.

This is the code for the html form:

```
<form>
  <h5>From:</h5>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="fromName">Name</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Full Name" id="fromName">
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="fromContactNo">Contact No.</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="08xxx" id="fromContactNo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="fromAddress">Address</label>
      <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Full Address" id="fromAddress"></textarea>

      <!-- break -->

      <h5>To:</h5>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="toName">Name</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Full Name" id="toName">
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="toContactNo">Contact No.</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="08xxx" id="toContactNo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="toAddress">Address</label>
      <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Full Address" id="toAddress"></textarea>

      <!-- break -->
      <h5>Delivery Details:</h5>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="u-full-width">
              <label for="itemDesc">Item description</label>
              <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Item Description here" id="itemDesc"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- break -->
        </br>
      <button class="button-primary" id="add-order">Send</button>
    </form>
```

And the javascript function is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $fromName = $('#fromName');
var $fromContactNo = $('#fromContactNo');
var $fromAddress = $('#fromAddress');
var $toName = $('#toName');
var $toContactNo = $('#toContactNo');
var $toAddress = $('#toAddress');
var $itemDesc = $('#itemDesc');
var $addOrder = $('#add-order');

$addOrder.on('click', function(){

    var newOrder = {
        "from": {
            "name": $fromName.val(),
            "phone_no": $fromContactNo.val(),
            "address": $fromAddress.val(),
        },
        "to": {
            "name": $toName.val(),
            "phone_no": $toContactNo.val(),
            "address": $toAddress.val(),
        },
        "item": $itemDesc.val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://myUrl.firebaseio.com/order.json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(newOrder),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Order added!", data);
      }
    });
});
});
```

I tried to mess around with the form and cannot find anything that breaks it. The console also showed no error.

Comment: what does this show `"Order added!", data`? how can you tell it is not submitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issue here. The first is that you hook to the click event of the `button`. This means that the `form` submission is still happening. When that happens the page is effectively reloaded as you have not given the `form` any `action` attribute, which is in turn preventing the AJAX call from completing. To fix this you should always hook to the `submit` event of the `form` and use `preventDefault()` to stop the default submission from occurring.

Secondly you only retrieve the `val()` properties of the input elements on load of the page. At that point the user has not interacted with them. Instead you should get their values just before you send them in the AJAX request.

Try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  

    var $fromName = $('#fromName');
    var $fromContactNo = $('#fromContactNo');
    var $fromAddress = $('#fromAddress');
    var $toName = $('#toName');
    var $toContactNo = $('#toContactNo');
    var $toAddress = $('#toAddress');
    var $itemDesc = $('#itemDesc');

    var newOrder = {
        "from": {
            "name": $fromName.val(),
            "phone_no": $fromContactNo.val(),
            "address": $fromAddress.val(),
        },
        "to": {
            "name": $toName.val(),
            "phone_no": $toContactNo.val(),
            "address": $toAddress.val(),
        },
        "item": $itemDesc.val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://myUrl.firebaseio.com/order.json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: newOrder, // no need for JSON.stringify here
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Order added!", data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sending to the same domain? cors request need to be allowed in order to do so

Comment: OP is using Firebase which is a well known storage service. They allow CORS requests

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it works! thanks so much. Although I am still not sure on how the form was able to recognize that my button is a 'submit' button without linking it to an id or something. btw, the JSON.stringify is still needed when I try your solution

Comment: No problem, glad to help. WRT the button, all buttons are `type="submit"` by default. jQuery should encode the JSON for you before sending, but stick with whatever works :)